# python send pdf file with Microsoft teams bot

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

and i need create option for send pdf file. For now i do if in chat send @bot send pdf, then sending basic test card code bellow.

```
async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
    self._add_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
    if " send pdf" in  turn_context.activity.text:
        cardAtt = self.thumbnail_card()
        msg_activity = MessageFactory.attachment(cardAtt)
        await turn_context.send_activity(msg_activity)
    else:
        return await turn_context.send_activity(
            f"You sent : {turn_context.activity.text}"
            )
def thumbnail_card(self) -> Attachment:
  card = ThumbnailCard()
  card.images = [ThumbnailUrl(url="https://pypi.org/static/images/logo-large.72ad8bf1.svg")]
  card.title = "Bot builder sample card"
  card.subtitle = "SDK Version 4.9"
  card.text = "Thumbnail card is the one of the card type in Bot Framework"
  return CardFactory.thumbnail_card(card)
```

Maybe possible change thumbnail card to send pdf file in the chat and allow users to download it? in `manifest.json` file i allow  `"supportsFiles": true,`
So any idea how to do it? its not a lot information how to send pdf file with Microsoft bot. so maybe you will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

General guidance I think is not to actually send **a file** but rather **a link** to a file - it supports better organisational document/record management, for instance, for the document to remain hosted in SharePoint, as an example, and for you to just send a link to the doc in your thumbnail card (or whatever). Of course the file could be hosted somewhere else (Azure Blob for example).

Comment: can be the link, pdf file are in flask project so easily can set the link of pdf file, but how to do it? can you give example for python code in my case for what?

Comment: oh yes I see now, apologies, didn't read the code sample properly. Offhand, I don't know if svg is support - that *might* be issue. Perhaps save it as a png and test using that.